# Generic type inference in object literal with function values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Consider the following sample code:

```
interface EntrySettings<T> {
  create: (index: number) => T;
  evaluate: (entry: T) => number;
}

function createEntry<T>(settings: EntrySettings<T>): T {
  return settings.create(0);
}

// return type is "string"
createEntry({
  create: () => "foobar",
  evaluate: entry => entry.length,
});

// return type is "unknown"
createEntry({
  create: i => "foobar",
  evaluate: entry => entry.length,
});
```

The return type is valid if the `create` method does not take its argument, but when it does, TypeScript seems to not know where to infer the `T` type.

Order of the fields seems to not have any impact on this behavior.

Is there any way to implement this correctly in the current form? (without explicitly specifying `T` nor the arguments of the functions)

Comment: Can you try `createEntry({ create: (i: number) => "foobar", evaluate: entry => entry.length });`?  My guess: if you don't annotate `i`, the compiler decides to defer inferring the type of `create` until later, which messes things up.

Comment: That would work for sure, but this sample is very simplified and in my real code there is no way to annotate it without making the code much less readable, that's why I want to keep it as it is.

Comment: You're going to have to change *something*, though.  How about unpackaging `EntrySettings<T>` and make a `entrySettings()` function to assemble it?  [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLigTwMoTGUAcwGcAeAFQD5kBvAWAChlnkEoI5IAuZAClAAmEAB48QAVwC2AI2gBKZAF5q5ANyMWyCADc4AG3GcIPXhAyYe5BcuQSZ0dQwC+jRjHEgEBAPYgt53HwiMipeDRY2Dm40ALwCEBIKSgBtACJIo1SAXQAacOYdfUNo9DAsQPjEqjTCg0ysxjkeUvK44KTafOR2MHEoPxpWdiMcrV06yGQnRxcGNw8vYF8hqIgWzCTeYjaE4mbYoN2kpuRyTqYWHr6-bcOSADoMyF4ABjkZxie181MDyuIwhdmMAlNR+PcwN5UMIAA6+MwEfS8OSjVIwbzeaRwKCpFFdBFYUH+MqYe56MyEMAACzyDDk7yAA)

Comment: I thought about this too, the problem is that I make a library and this way of defining it would be very unintuitive for others I think. I guess I will need to change much more things than that to work around it

Comment: You could give the compiler a little help though, by explicitly defining the type of the generic instead of infering it: `createEntry<string>({ create: i => "foobar", evaluate: entry => entry.length });`.

Comment: If your types are so complex that type annotations are unfeasible then I'd suggest giving people builders for it anyway, so I'm not sure why that would be less intuitive than an object that can't be reasonably annotated.   But okay... what do you want to see as an answer to this question?  I'm happy to write any of this up as an answer but it sounds like you aren't satisfied with the suggestions.  Consider editing the question to specify more exactly your criteria for success; as it stands "annotate more things" asks the question as asked.  Good luck!

Comment: I guess I will use the builder then, which I didn't want to use because of the generic type but this is probably the best option here. Thanks for your replies guys!